# Understanding that on a square in $R^2$, given the $\ell^{\infty}$ norm, there are an infinite number of geodesics between any two points

Tags: normed-spaces

What is the $\ell^{\infty}$ norm in $R^2$. I read that on a square in $R^2$, given the $\ell^{\infty}$ norm, there are an infinite number of geodesics between any two points. I don't understand this statement.

Is it just $|x-y|_{\ell^{\infty}}=\max(\{|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|\})$

Comment: What is your definition of geodesic?

Comment: @ArcticChar- Path of minimal length. Doesn't have to be a "straight line"

Comment: Then i dont understand your last sentence. There is no path mentioned.

Comment: Is this question asking about the assertion in the title, or is this question asking about the definition of the $\ell^\infty$ norm? (Your definition of that norm is correct.)

Comment: **Hint:** Consider the following line segments from $(0,0)$ to $(2,0)$ for any $t\in [-1, 1]$:
$$(0,0) \ \leadsto (1,t)\ \leadsto (2,0)$$

Comment: The length of a curve $\phi: [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ is the supremum of $\sum_{i=1}^n \|\phi(t_i) - \phi(t_{i-1})\|$, taken over all partitions $0 = t_0 < t_1 < \ldots < t_n = 1$. Since one of those partitions is $0 = t_0 < t_1 = 1$, the length of $\phi$ is always at least as great as $\|\phi(1) - \phi(0)\|$. For the $\ell^\infty$ norm, it is easy to see that a line segment has this minimal length. However, unlike the Euclidean norm, there are other curves with the same length.